# How my page scroll down with smooth scrolling

Tags: jquery, html

I used the script for smooth scrolling my page, but the script does not work i am very confused where i am wrong please help me

My script is:

```
$(".scroll").click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     //calculate destination place
     var dest=0;
     if($(this.hash).offset().top > $(document).height()-$(window).height()){
          dest=$(document).height()-$(window).height();
     }else{
          dest=$(this.hash).offset().top;
     }
     //go to destination
     $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:dest}, 1000,'swing');
 });
```

and i used .scroll in anchor tag this type:

```
<a class="scroll" href="#bot">Click here</a>
```

Please help me!

Comment: *but the script does not work* is very vague

Comment: Sorry, you said this script is very vague but i seen this script on various site.

Comment: can you make a fiddle plz?

Comment: Mr. Moe Assaad i am realy sorry i can't understand your means.

Comment: Mr. Alien could you help me

Comment: can you give us the html code of the page?

Answer (score 0):

for smooth scrolling I would recommend using this :

(modified slightly from a script I found on github - though I don't remember the original author - grabbed it from one of my projects)

```
jQuery.fn.anchorAnimate = function(settings) {

settings = jQuery.extend({
        speed : 1100
}, settings);

return this.each(function(){
    var caller = this
    $(caller).click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        var locationHref = window.location.href
        var elementClick = $(caller).attr("href")

        var destination = $(elementClick).offset().top;
        $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({
            scrollTop: destination
        }, settings.speed, function() {
                window.location.hash = elementClick
        });
        return false;
    })
})
}
```

Then Call it like so :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(".menu li a").anchorAnimate({
        speed: 600
    });

});
```